# Chart.js 2.9.3 multiline labels compatibility

Tags: angular, chart.js

In newest releases like 4.x.x, break lines on legend labels can be created using an nested array such as `labels = [["First label first row","First label second row"],"Second label"]`
However in my chartjs version 2.9.3 this functionallity seems not supported. Is there  something Iam missing, or any alternative without more complex functions?
Note that Iam using Angular 7, so I wouldn't prefer to use getElementbyId or ViewChild